# CoreComponentFactoryDidn't find class "android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory"

Tags: android, crash

I got sudden crash in my google pixel 2 having android 9 version.
Is there any hint what is the reason behind that and it is not reproducible every time.

detail logs...

> Didn't find class "android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory" on
>   path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.google.android.deskclock-o_Iury9TRKVebStZjRrd0g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.google.android.deskclock-o_Iury9TRKVebStZjRrd0g==/lib/arm64,
>   /system/lib64]]

Answer (score 7):

Just clean the build and run it will go away

Comment: I caught similar exception, but without crash, on API 28 emulator. Clean and rebuild probably helped to avoid this message, I will test further.

Comment: Well, after a week this exception returned on the same emulator.

Comment: I'm having the same issue but I can't really understand what's causing it. It happened all of a sudden.

Comment: Does anyone knows the answer? Thanks